# SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame, from same domian

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, same-origin-policy

I got this errors message when trying to access iframe location:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.soinfit.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://soinfit.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

The domain, protocol and port are the same so why I get this error?

Comment: `www` counts as a domain, which affects origin. so, according to the spec, they don't match.